# PhantomJS - Injected JS Does Not Run After JS Error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a phantomJS script that looks like so:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { //give page a couple seconds to load before injecting our scripts
        //include our version of jQuery so that our injected JS can run properly
        page.includeJs('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
            if (!page.injectJs(JS)) {
                console.log("unable to inject JS at " + JS);
                phantom.exit(1);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
```

The JS being injected is what runs and eventually executes the window.callPhantom call that terminates the script. The issue is that this JS is injected onto a page dictated by the end user. The end user could supply e.g. http://www.google.com or anything else.

It appears that if the page has JS errors, the injected Javascript will not be run. Since I do not control the content of the page, there is no way for me to prevent these JS errors.

Is there a way to get my injected JavaScript to run despite previous JS errors generated on the page?

Comment: I don't observe such behavior - local injected script successfully runs after the page with a deliberate js error is loaded. Can you share a minimal example?